# Firebase Filter by Date

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data:

[image: Data]

I am looking for a way to filter the dates using a custom date range.
      I've   seen some examples online where they have queried for date,
      but the timestamp has always been the key which isn't possible in my case.
       I have tried the below code and it didn't work.

```
  var rootRef1 = firebase.database().ref().child("Users").orderByChild('type')
  .startAt("2019-01-05").endat("2019-01-10");


    rootRef1.on("child_added",snap => {
     var name=snap.child("fullname").val();
    var email= snap.child("email").val();
     var address= snap.child("address").val();
     var contact= snap.child("contact").val();
     var status=snap.child("status").val();
     var type=snap.child("type").val();
     var date=snap.child("regdate").val();
     console.log(name);   
   });
```

This does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're trying to filter on date values, but you're ordering on `type` That's not how Firebase Database queries work: you always first order on a property/value, and then filter on that same property/value.

So to order/filter on `regdate`:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("Users").orderByChild('regdate')
  .startAt("2019-01-05").endAt("2019-01-10");
```

Note that I also changed `endat` to `endAt` (with an uppercase `A`). The `endat` you had, will give a syntax error.

---

You're now ending at `2019-01-10`. Since your actual values include a time, they will all fall right after this value. If you also want to include the users who registered on `2019-01-10` itself, use:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("Users").orderByChild('regdate')
  .startAt("2019-01-05").endAt("2019-01-10 23:59:59");
```