# Why doesn't sort/filter work on this Realtime Database query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have data in our Firebase Realtime Database formatted like this:

```
{
    events: {
        hourly: {
            abc123: {
                startDate: "Wed, 26 Jun 2019 18:32:27 GMT",
                endDate: "Wed, 26 Jun 2019 23:59:59 GMT",
                someValue: 5
            },
            def456: {
                startDate: "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:45:08 GMT",
                endDate: "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 23:59:59 GMT",
                someValue: 10
            },
        }
    }
}
```

In our Firebase Cloud Functions code, I query the data like this:

```
const now = new Date().toUTCString();
const ref = admin.database().ref('events/hourly');
const hourly = await ref.orderByChild("endDate").startAt(now).once('value');
```

However, the database returns all entries from `events/hourly` - they are not ordered or filtered.

I've compared my code to the official documentation and other SE questions (e.g. [Firebase Filter by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54171488/firebase-filter-by-date)) and can't see what's wrong with my code - unless Firebase doesn't recognize that the query is a date and is trying to sort/filter alphabetically?

Comment: `endDate` is not a child of `events.hourly`.

Comment: @StackSlave Firebase Database queries look at each child node under the location queried, and find the property your order/filter on. Since `abc123`, and `def456` have a `endDate` property, that looks correct to me.

Comment: You're not sorting by date, but by a string that (to you as a human) looks like a date. To the database however it is just a string, so it sorts it lexicographically. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216858/firebase-query-by-date-string/38226376#38226376, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52732340, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52931580 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/40204402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is just an issue of trying to sort alphabetically instead of recognizing the value is a date. Solution is to use `.toISOString()` instead of `.toUTCString()` when creating and querying the entries.